# Why SFINAE report error in function overloading

Tags: c++, sfinae

Follwing code can't compile,I just want testing SFINAE,why it can't compile?

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T>
class TestVoid {
    template<std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }

    template<std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "none void\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    TestVoid<void> t;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate the class template, all of the member function declarations must be valid. In your case, one of them won't be. Instead, you can delegate `func` to another function template.

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hwYws1nXDjXrcvfv)

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>> * = nullptr>
void func() {
    std::cout << "void\n";
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>> * = nullptr>
void func() {
    std::cout << "none void\n";
}

template<typename T>
class TestVoid {
  public:
    void func_member() {
        func<T>();
    }
};
```

Or, if you want to keep the actual implementation of `func` as a member function:

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dKqk8AwbJESVPrKt)

```
template<typename T>
class TestVoid {
  public:
    void func_member() {
        func<T>();
    }
  private:
    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<U>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }

    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<U>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "none void\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the conditions of `std::enable_if` don't depend on template parameter of `func` themselves.

You might change the code to

```
template<typename T>
struct TestVoid {
    template<typename X = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<X>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "void\n";
    }

    template<typename X = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<X>> * = nullptr>
    void func() {
        std::cout << "none void\n";
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/81odYqErT)